# Is there any way to update table only for chosen values in generic way?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am creating a generic solution that allows me to build JSON files based on data from the database. To generate JSON I am using SQL Server features. My database storage is based on key-values with some additional columns like ID and Version of JSON data, so my main table looks like this:

[image]

> To build JSON from an above table I am using pivot to transform table, so my result is like below and from this position it's easy to convert to JSON.

```
SELECT * into #temptable1
FROM
(SELECT [Key], value FROM MyTable Where ID=1 AND Version=1) as source
PIVOT
(
 MIN(value)
 FOR [Key] IN ([name], [title], [isFinanced])
) as pvt 

SELECT * FROM #temptable1
```

[image]

and now is the point where I have a problem, In my main table I have different versions of JSON values, which I would like to use for building different JSON files, If I do pivot for two different versions of my Json values I got this result:

[image]

Is there any way to move only missing values from the first table to the second one? So my result will be like (keeping value in version 2 and update the rest of the values with version 1):

[image]

The problem here is that the value versions can be different (so the values can change), which means I cannot assign values directly.

I have tried with UNION, but it gives me two rows, in my case, it should be 'like' merged or updated. Is there any way to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can use `WITH TIES` in concert with a `row_number()`

```
SELECT * 
 Into  #temptable1
 FROM  (SELECT Top 1 with ties
               [Key]
              ,value 
         FROM  MyTable 
         Where ID=1
         Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By [ID],[Key] Order By [Version] Desc)
       ) as source
PIVOT
(
 MIN(value)
 FOR [Key] IN ([name], [title], [isFinanced])
) as pvt 

SELECT * FROM #temptable1
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you for an answer, code works nice, but what in a case when I got more versions and I want to be more specified, for example, I have 3 versions of values and want to pick up a version 2, if I use DESC it always takes the last one (so the version 3).

Comment: @kisiel Just add that to the WHERE  for example  WHERE ID=1 and [Version] <= 2

Comment: @kisiel Always happy to help